# testing to see if a dvd has css encryption?

Tags: dvd, copy-protection

I occasionally buy DVDs of older TV series off of eBay and one thing I like to do before leaving feedback is to see if the DVD is legit or not by testing for the presence of CSS encryption. I figure a legit US DVD will have: CSS encryption and be Region 1 encoded.

I used to use AnyDVD to tell me if the DVD was legit but that computer has since failed and, in any event, since I'm not trying to circumvent copy protection, I'm wondering if there's a free tool that can give me this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use VideoLAN (VLC) to play a single VOB instead of the whole DVD or DVD-folder.

VLC does not de-CSS a single VOB, so the scrambling is immediately visible.